# Reliable way to redirect to last page

Tags: controllers

Is there a reliable way in magento to redirect to the last page.

I have a small form that i want to redirect to the previous page if an error occurred.

The form sits on the product page and redirects to another page when completed successfully.  However, I would like to redirect back to the product page if an error occurred.

My action url is `/my/module/submit`

Also when i say reliable, i mean that `redirectReferer` cant be relied on

Comment: RedirectReferer is reliable enough for Magento's Adminhtml to rely on pretty exclusively for back buttons?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Magento relies on the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` value for redirect logic without qualm; see [`Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php#L761):

```
/**
 * Set referer url for redirect in responce
 *
 * @param   string $defaultUrl
 * @return  Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action
 */
protected function _redirectReferer($defaultUrl=null)
{

    $refererUrl = $this->_getRefererUrl();
    if (empty($refererUrl)) {
        $refererUrl = empty($defaultUrl) ? Mage::getBaseUrl() : $defaultUrl;
    }

    $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($refererUrl);
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Identify referer url via all accepted methods (HTTP_REFERER, regular or base64-encoded request param)
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function _getRefererUrl()
{
    $refererUrl = $this->getRequest()->getServer('HTTP_REFERER');
    if ($url = $this->getRequest()->getParam(self::PARAM_NAME_REFERER_URL)) {
        $refererUrl = $url;
    }
    if ($url = $this->getRequest()->getParam(self::PARAM_NAME_BASE64_URL)) {
        $refererUrl = Mage::helper('core')->urlDecode($url);
    }
    if ($url = $this->getRequest()->getParam(self::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED)) {
        $refererUrl = Mage::helper('core')->urlDecode($url);
    }

    if (!$this->_isUrlInternal($refererUrl)) {
        $refererUrl = Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
    }
    return $refererUrl;
}
```

If you aren't content to rely on the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, the only thing which you can do is **store the most recently-visited URL in session** and **create a getter for this value which handles the case when someone navigates directly to the site**.